# div span hover in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

The page has multiple divs. Each div is having an anchor tag and a span.
The hover of the div enables the span but does not replace the css properly after mouseout in IE. Sometimes, the hover of multiple divs remain open at the same time.
Can you please help. Preferred - CSS fix.

Code snippet:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="fL w320 gd_bsas_tbl_descr">
    <a onclick="ToPD('1675811');" id="ld_1675811" class="csLinksNewProdDescSL">HP 4y 4h24x7 Onsite...&nbsp;</a>
    <span class="gd_bsas_tbl_descr_in">HP 4y 4h24x7 w/DMR ProLiant  and Defective Media Retention</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.gd_bsas_tbl_descr {
    font-color:#424242;
    position:relative;
}
.gd_bsas_tbl_descr a {
    color:#424242;
}
.gd_bsas_tbl_descr_in {
    background:#e4e5f0 url('/images/bsas_g.png') repeat-x;
    border:1px solid #767676;
    position:absolute;
    top:14px;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    width:400px;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#424242;
    z-index:2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.gd_bsas_tbl_descr:hover .gd_bsas_tbl_descr_in {
    display:block;
}
.gd_bsas_tbl_descr:hover .gd_bsas_tbl_descr_in:hover {
}
.gd_bsas_tbl_descr_in2 {
    background:#e4e5f0 url('/images/bsas_g.png') repeat-x;
    border:1px solid #767676;
    position:absolute;
    top:14px;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#424242;
    z-index:2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t9zu/) with the supplied code.

Comment: This is working fine in my IE.  What version are you using?

Comment: Working fine for me too in IE11.